# Send PHP confirmation email admin email is sent

Tags: php, ajax, email, phpmailer

I am using AJAX and PHP to send an email with data from a contact form.  I am using the following PHP:

```
            if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
                // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
                http_response_code(200);
            } else {
                // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
                http_response_code(500);
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
            }
```

This is working fine, but if this first email is sent, I would also like to send a confirmation email with new parameters. I thought I would be able to just set another mail() function after the 200 response code like:

```
       if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            mail($email, $confirmation_subject, $confirmation_content, $confirmation_headers);
        } else {
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }
```

But this is causing neither email to be sent.  What is the proper way to implement a confirmation email if the admin email is sent.

Comment: This looks ok, so you need to do some basic debugging to see what is happening. Use a debugger to step through the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send headers back the execution basically stops.  I've never seen it documented, but I've been bit by this before.  Try switching the order of these two:

```
http_response_code(200);
mail($email, $confirmation_subject, $confirmation_content, $confirmation_headers);
```

to

```
mail($email, $confirmation_subject, $confirmation_content, $confirmation_headers);
http_response_code(200);
```